# Navigation tab for each div with shadow border

Tags: html, css

```css
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#nav>div {}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="nav">
  <div>up</div>
  <div>down</div>
  <div>left</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>

</html>
```

How do I make it so that each of the div's inside of `#nav` appear inside of a yellow box equal to the length of the `#nav`, regardless of how many `div` there are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**

```css
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
}

#nav>div {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border: 1px solid aquamarine;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <div>up</div>
    <div>down</div>
    <div>left</div>
    <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add more yellow box it's total length equal to the length of the #nav .

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```css
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left : 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top  : 0px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#nav div {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
        <div>up</div>
        <div>down<div>
        <div>left</div>
        <div>right</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want each of the divs to have their own yellow box with a border

Answer (score 0):

Try position:relative for #nav and position:absolute;width:100% for div's

Answer (score 0):

```css
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left : 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top  : 0px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#nav div {
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:10px;
  border: 1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
        <div>up</div>
        <div>down</div>
        <div>left</div>
        <div>right</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is **obscure** but my answer for what i found out is :

```css
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left : 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top  : 0px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#nav div {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow : 0 0 3px 1px #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
        <div>up</div>
        <div>down<div>
        <div>left</div>
        <div>right</div>
    </div>
```